# Update multiple columns from one table with one column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I have three tables that are structured in this format:

```
DECLARE @A
(
    TypeName varchar(100),
    Type1 varchar(3),
    Type2 varchar(3),
    Type3 varchar(3),
    Type4 varchar(3),
    Type5 varchar(3),
    Type6 varchar(3)
)

Data:
| Bob   | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| Steve | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| Bill  | null | null | null | null | null | null |
...

DECLARE @B
(
    NameID int,
    Name varchar(100)
)

Data:
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Steve |
| 3 | Bill |
...

DECLARE @C
(
    NameID int,
    Type int
)

Data:
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
...
```

I want to update the `Type#` columns in table `@A` with a condition based on the `Type` column of table `@C`. Here is an SQL query that I have attempted to use:

```
UPDATE @A SET
    Type1 = (CASE WHEN c.Type = 6 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type2 = (CASE WHEN c.Type = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type3 = (CASE WHEN c.Type = 2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type4 = (CASE WHEN c.Type = 3 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type5 = (CASE WHEN c.Type = 4 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type6 = (CASE WHEN c.Type = 5 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
FROM @A
    INNER JOIN @B b ON b.Name = TypeName
    INNER JOIN @C c ON c.NameID = b.NameID

SELECT * FROM @A
```

Instead of getting the expected values:

```
| Bob   | No | Yes | No  | Yes | No | No | <-- Correct
| Steve | No | Yes | No  | No  | No | No |
| Bill  | No | No  | Yes | No  | No | No |
```

I get these values:

```
| Bob   | No | Yes | No  | No  | No | No | <-- Incorrect (noticed the third column from the right being set to No instead of Yes)
| Steve | No | Yes | No  | No  | No | No |
| Bill  | No | No  | Yes | No  | No | No |
```

I have also tried re-writing the statement to be like this:

```
UPDATE @A SET
    Type1 = (CASE WHEN t.Type = 6 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type2 = (CASE WHEN t.Type = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type3 = (CASE WHEN t.Type = 2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type4 = (CASE WHEN t.Type = 3 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type5 = (CASE WHEN t.Type = 4 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
    Type6 = (CASE WHEN t.Type = 5 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),
FROM
(
    SELECT b.Name, c.Type
    FROM @C c
        INNER JOIN @B b on b.NameID = c.NameID
) t
WHERE t.Name = TypeName
```

But it still returned the latter results.

So why is it that the columns are not being updated correctly for the `TypeName` column `Bob` and how would I fix that so that I can get my expected values?

Comment: What is TypeAssigned6 in Table A?

Comment: It was suppose to be `Type6` It seems like the edit didn't save my changes correctly. I updated it

Comment: Are you sure you are getting only 3 rows when you join all 3 tables? You should get 4 rows

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion I'm sure I only get 3 rows since I'm only updating `@A` and not inserting. If I do a select on `@C` then I will get 4 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have several rows in @C per person. You'll have to first make it one row to be able to update the data:

```
select
  NameID,
  max(case Type when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Type1,
  max(case Type when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Type2,
  max(case Type when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Type3,
  max(case Type when 4 then 1 else 0 end) as Type4,
  max(case Type when 5 then 1 else 0 end) as Type5,
  max(case Type when 6 then 1 else 0 end) as Type6
from
  @C
group by
  NameID
```

Can't test this now, but you probably can even make the text there, with something like this:

> case when max(case Type when 1 the 1 else 0) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No'
>   end as Type1

You can use this as derived table in the update, or maybe collect the results first into another table variable

Comment: This works! But I do not get how `max()` helped with my problem? If I was to remove `max()` and then replace the 1s and 0s with Yes and No then it would cause my current issue.

Comment: When you have more than one row per person in the data, you're updating @A several times, and it just leaves the last data into there. You'll figure it out if you do the same thing as select -- there will be 2 rows for Bob with Yes in different column.